# Create new folder under existing virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, virtual-directory

How can I create **new folder** under existing virtual directory??

please show me example....

Dim a As String = Server.MapPath("/VirtualIRPictures")

"/VirtualIRPictures" = "C:/Inetpub/IRPictures/ (not showing me this although I set it up under 
the IIS

what I'm getting is path that is in my project which is not right

"C:\SourceCode\Software\Software\VirtualIRPictures"

I want that "/VirtualIRPictures" will give me this path ""C:/Inetpub/IRPictures/"  what should I do??

Comment: how did you try to create a new one? via .NET code or in the file system?

Comment: Please show your code and the error you get.

Comment: I re-wrote my question

Comment: Replace `Server.MapPath("/VirtualIRPictures")` with `Server.MapPath("/")`

Comment: Still I'm getting the same thing :  "C:\SourceCode\Software\Software\" I want to get what I set up under the IIS setting which is : C:\Inetpubb\IRPictures that is the physical path alias "VirtualIRPictures" why I'm getting folder that is with in my project??